# Android gradle fails once, succeeds the 2nd time

Tags: android, gradle

I have and Android app with a stable library supporting a completely auto-generated project sitting on top.

All code and resources reside in the library, and the auto-generated project only overrides some strings and Manifest items.

When I generate and build the project, every first time I get:

```
Execution failed for task ':myModule:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Crunching Cruncher my_resource.png failed, see logs
```

However, building again works perfectly, every second time.

What could be going on?

Comment: Please share the result of `gradle -v`

Comment: As in `verbose`, or `version`? My `-v` switch on the `gradlew` script means `version`

Comment: As version. Which version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: Gradle 2.2.1  rev 6fcb59c06f43a4e6b1bcb401f7686a8601a1fb4a linux64

Comment: Show your `build.gradle`. Also make sure you are using the latest `Gradle` version, which is 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent (minor) bug reported that certainly looks like it affects you.

Please take a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163378) where a project member mentions a temporary fix to the problem by

> as a workaround, set useNewCruncher to false in aaptOptions.